# Javascript - Setting a return to true in a function

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'm using a button element to submit values. I want to check, if the input fields are filled

*The 'required'-attribute does not work in this specific case, because I'm using pickadate.js, which disables that.*

I made a javascript-function that is called on a button click. To stop the button from submitting, I've set the return to false:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"
onclick="checkIfFilled(); return false;" 
data-loading-text="loading…">ButtonText</button>
```

Now I want to set the *return false;* to *return true;* using the javascript function *checkIfFilled()*

So if the check was successful, the data should be send like if there was no *return false;*

**Edit for those who may have the question in the future: The solution is to return the function, which returns either true or false whenever you want it.**

Thanks to Michael, musically_ut and Amani!

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Why not `onclick="return checkIfFilled()" ` ?

Comment: Remove the `return false;` from the HTML and return `true/false` from `checkIfFilled` itself.

Comment: I'm not used to javascript, but this solution is great! Thanks to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```html
<form method="post" action="#">
<input id="check_this" name="" value=""></input>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"
onclick="return checkIfFilled()" 
data-loading-text="loading…">ButtonText</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkIfFilled(){
      //if required input is empty retuen false if not return true
      if(document.getElementById("check_this").value != "") {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Even if I already got it, thats a good example for the future. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return checkIfFilled();" 
data-loading-text="loading…">ButtonText</button>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkIfFilled(){
      if(document.getElementById("textboxId").value.trim()!=="") {
         return true;
      }
</script>
```